# Can I ban or restrict a country based on IP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, spam-prevention

I get 6-10 sign ups from places like Nigeria and Ghana in Africa.  I'm currently capturing IPs so is it possible to restrict a range of IPs from a specific country?

If I can retrict them does it make more sense to add this range to my .htaccess file or restrict them at the site level?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the maxmind database:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip

and use this code:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Redirect multiple countries to a single page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(NI|GH)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. Use GEOIP. http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip

Comment: Thanks, I also just found: http://www.countryipblocks.net Has anyone used this and had luck?  Looks like it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Just google for GEOIP - there's a number of free services available you can also get a file, containing Country specific IP patterns. No services will give you 100% protection as it's possible to forge the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache's mod_geoip:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US BlockCountry
# ... place more countries here

Deny from env=BlockCountry
```